# Get the Bluetooth MAC Address of a Blackberry device

Tags: blackberry, bluetooth

I'd like to get the Bluetooth MAC Address of the device the app is running on, even when it's not connected to another BT device. Is this even possible? Can you even turn on/off the Bluetooth radio via an API?

I'm not familiar with the Blackberry SDK, but I am familiar with Android and iOS. I'm aware that it's not possible on iOS because the API is not exposed (unless you are rooted). I know very well how to do it on Android.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? I will either learn to deal with the Blackberry SDK or hire somebody to do the work for the app I need, but I want to be a little bit familiar with this.

Comment: Have you looked at the Bluetooth API from RIM?

Comment: Yes, I looked at the docs. Couldn't found what I need, maybe I didn't look deep enough.

Answer (score 3):

I think we can user getDeviceAddress() method to get device address.
this method returns data in byte array.

```
BluetoothSerialPortInfo[] info = BluetoothSerialPort.getSerialPortInfo();
byte[] btAddress = info[0].getDeviceAddress();
```

We need to convert this byte array to hex.

```
ByteArrayUtilities.byteArrayToHex();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this work only for current connections? Also, will it get the address for *this* device or for the remote device? Thank you.